# I'm trying to send Bitcoin but it's telling me I need a pin to send it why?

Tags: transactions, wallet, sending

I want to send Bitcoin to my wife because she's out of town and needs some money that's the only way I can give it to her but it's asking me for a pin what is my PIN I have no idea what it is or why it's even on please help?

```
      Thank you for your time
```

Comment: Who/what is "it" exactly? You need to be more specific, but it sounds like you are using a wallet service/provider of some sort in such case you need to contact them.

Comment: Do you not know the pin code you set up?  Maybe ask your wife if she's the one that set it up.

Comment: I recommend using Venmo or wiring her money via western union. Its probably faster than the 20+ hours youve already waited for an answer to this question.  How do you guys not have mainstream payment options available to you?  Where are you even at that having crypto is even essential to your daily lives?

Comment: I recommend you triple check that you are not being scammed.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the wallet software or hardware you are using has a password attached to it in the form of a PIN - which is a string of numbers that you use to decrypt the private key, so that you can create and sign transactions.